# How do I delete the comments at the top after every 10

Tags: php, html, comments

I have a website where people post their twitter url and people can follow them from there. The url posting is handled by a php posting script my question is, can I delete the first comments after 20 comments so that they dont just continue down the page forever? I want it to work like this site http://tumblrplug.com/ NOTE: I have the comments stored on a mysql database along with a counter for each comment.

The code for commenting is:

```
<?php
require('connect.php');
$query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comment ORDER BY id DESC");
while($rows=mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
     $id=$rows['id'];
     $dname=$rows['name'];
     $dcomment=$rows['comment'];

     echo '<font  id = "username_word" color="red">username:</font>' ."<a href='$dname' id = 'name' style='color: #77cde6' STYLE='TEXT-DECORATION: NONE'>$dname</a>"."<font class='dash' color='red'> - </font> "."<div id='comment'>$dcomment</div>" 
  ."<a href='$dname'><img src='http://i45.tinypic.com/2yltzkg.png' width ='30px' height ='30px' border='0' alt='follow' id='followbtn'></a>" ;    

     }
?>
```

THE CODE FOR QUERYING IS THIS:

```
<?php
require('connect.php');
$query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comment ORDER BY id DESC");
while($rows=mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
     $id=$rows['id'];
     $dname=$rows['name'];
     $dcomment=$rows['comment'];

     echo '<font  id = "username_word" color="red">username:</font>' ."<a href='$dname' id = 'name' style='color: #77cde6' STYLE='TEXT-DECORATION: NONE'>$dname</a>"."<font class='dash' color='red'> - </font> "."<div id='comment'>$dcomment</div>" 
  ."<a href='$dname'><img src='http://i45.tinypic.com/2yltzkg.png' width ='30px' height ='30px' border='0' alt='follow' id='followbtn'></a>" ;    

     }
?>
```

Comment: `ORDER BY id DESC` has the potential to be out of chronological order. You should probably have a column for DATETIME and then sort it by that.

Comment: i still cant do it i have order by id desc in my comment code but please i need some direction can you explain it a bit simpler like where would i put this order by id desc its there at the begining of the query code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you re-querying each time you load from the comment table? If so, you could just limit the number of rows being returned to 20.

SELECT * FROM comment ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 20

Comment: but then will people still be able to post comments after the 20 is reached? because i want the oldest comments to be deleted to make room for more comments ile put the querying code

Comment: @TinasheShoko Of course - you're just focusing on returning the comments here. Every time a comment is posted, I'm assuming you re-query to display them - returning the last 20 (you might want to order by a DATETIME as noted above). This means you'll always get the latest 20 comments.

Comment: thanks but im quite new to php i get what you mean but the implementation is what im lost on how would i do that maybe a line of code to help please thanks for they replies btw @David J

Comment: so in my query code i would put something like this in my query code and then add a datetime collum to my database  <code>$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id DESC  " )  </code>

Comment: @David J i still cant do it i have order by id desc in my comment code but please i need some direction can you explain it a bit simpler